# "unknown command: `/''" with a simple replacement command

Tags: sed

I am trying to run the following code in Kali:

```
cat /usr/share/wordlists/dirbuster/apache-user-enum-1.0.txt |
sed “s/~//g” > /usr/share/wordlists/users.txt
```

to delete a matching character '~' and replace with blank but it returns the error "`` sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unknown command: `/' ``" instead.

Any ideas how to work around this ?

Comment: @Gilles I have tried your suggestion but it still gives me the same problem... I have used the following : sed '/~//g' /usr/share/wordlists/dirbuster/apache-user-enum-1.0.txt  > /usr/share/wordlists/users.txt and followed by the error:
sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unknown command: `/'

Comment: You miss the `s` at the  beginning of the substitution !

Comment: @Gilles Oh thanks for pointing out ! It worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Your double quotes looks suspicious, it's not regular double quotes, instead, use single quotes like this :

```
sed 's/~//g' file.txt > /usr/share/wordlists/users.txt
```

Your quotes are [unicode](/questions/tagged/unicode) character `U+201C`, should be `U+22`, take care of what you type with your keyboard